# How to take screenshot of background app in python 2.7 for mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, screenshot

I have been trying to make a program that notifies me when a number changes on an app. I have been using ImageGrab and then pytesseract which works but I can only figure out how to take the screenshot when I can visually see the number. It would be very nice if there was a way to take an image of the app if it was minimized (not visible on the screen) so I could work on other things as it ran. I also need the picture of a certain part of that app I need to do a bounding box within the app of where the picture is taken.

This is what I am currently using which takes a certain part of the whole screen:

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1400,875,1445,905))

I think there might be a way to do it with Quartz but I could not find out how to do a region of a background app.

Comment: You can't take a **screen**shot of something that's not on your **screen**.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to take screenshots of windows that are running in the background with the `screencapture` api in MacOS. You can see the documentation by typing `man screencapture` in the terminal.

For your use case it would look something like this:

```
screencapture -l <windowId> -R <x,y,w,h>
```

As you mentioned, you can use `Quartz` to find the desired `windowId`:

```py
from Quartz import CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowListOptionAll

windowName = 'Desktop' # change this to the window you are looking for

def findWindowId():

    windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
        kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID)

    for window in windowList:
        if(windowName.lower() in window.get('kCGWindowName', '').lower()):
            return window['kCGWindowNumber']

    return None
```

You can find a fully working example [here](https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/2116a834f5e4e1cd069659463a07dde5)

**Note:** From my testings, if you minimise(`cmd + m`) or hide(`cmd + h`) a window, taking a screenshot of it will only capture the moment before it was hidden. You would need to keep the window opened for it to work--but it is ok to keep it behind other windows. Tested on MacOS `v10.15.7`.

Comment: If you're not sure if this will work for minimized apps, what's the point? OP is asking to screen a minimized app.

Comment: @ManuelFedele The point is that OP can `work on other things` while it runs. It will work even if there are other apps covering it. I will make this clearer in the answer. Thanks for your comment!